# Create an HTML table rows in JS from iterated JSON array element objects

Tags: javascript, json

I search for something using wiki API and I get JSON which has the data I want in query.search like so

```
0 {ns: 0, title: "Help", size: 3677, wordcount: 433, snippet: "<span class=\"searchmatch\">Help</span> is any form …mmand-line shells that invokes documentations and", …}

1 {ns: 0, title: "Online help", size: 7326, wordcount: 380, snippet: "(HTML), which includes HTML <span class=\"searchmat…earchmatch\">help</span> is also provided via live", …}

2 {ns: 0, title: "Help desk", size: 9491, wordcount: 1296, snippet: "A <span class=\"searchmatch\">help</span> desk is a …ated to a company's or institution's products and", …}

...
```

I need the value of title so for loop iterates through it with

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.query.search.length; i++) {
var result = data.query.search[i];
var title = result.title; 
console.log(title); }
```

Now I want to create a table and put each title value into separate rows, I use this code but it doesn't work

```
  var table = document.getElementById("resultTable");

  var row = table.insertRow(i);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(i);

  cell1.innerHTML = data.query.search[i].title;
```

In the HTML part I have

```
<div>
<table id="resultTable"></table>
</div>
```

Do I have to put the table creation code into a separate for loop or the use of `[i]` is wrong?

Here is the whole code:

```
function build_wiki_search_url(pattern) {
var base_url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php";
var format = "&format=json";
var request_url = "?  action=query&format=json&prop=info&inprop=url&list=search&srsearch=";
var url = base_url + request_url + pattern;
return url;
}
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#gosearch").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Submit button clicked");
    var pattern = $("#search").val();
    var url = build_wiki_search_url(pattern);
    $.ajax( {
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data.query.search); 

 for (var i = 0; i < data.query.search.length; i++) {
 var result = data.query.search[i];
 var title = result.title;
  console.log(title);

 function drawTableHor(data) {
var table1 = document.getElementById("resultTable1");
for (var i = 0; i < data.query.search.length; i++) {
  var row = table1.insertRow();
  for(var prop in data.query.search[i]) {
    if(prop !== 'title') continue;
      var cell = row.insertCell();
      cell.innerHTML = data.query.search[i][prop];
  }
}
};
   drawTableHor(data);

   }
```

Comment: it all depends on how you define the javascript.  Are you going to create all the associated tags with javascript as well, or are you going to iterate a termplate?  I mean, there are multiple ways to go about this approach.  I usually likely templating but younger me liked putting everything possible in javascript, which blurred the line of MVC design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var row = table.insertRow(i);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(i);
```

Here you use the same `i` (inside the cycle I suppose). While it is ok for rows because at each step of iteration you deal with a new row, I guess it doesn't work well for cells because from the second step on you try to insert a cell at a weird index: 2, 3 etc. while you have nothing at 1st, 1st and 2d positions etc. respectively.

With you code I got a table with only 1st title inside. I would say, you don't need those indexes in the functions at all and assuming you want to "put each title value into separate rows" check the code below. Also notice that there is an alternative there that places data "vertically" = title values are in one row):

```js
var data = {
query: {
search: [
{ns: 0, title: "Help", size: 3677, wordcount: 433, snippet: "<span class=\"searchmatch\">Help</span> is any form …mmand-line shells that invokes documentations and"},
{ns: 0, title: "Online help", size: 7326, wordcount: 380, snippet: "(HTML), which includes HTML <span class=\"searchmat…earchmatch\">help</span> is also provided via live"},
{ns: 0, title: "Online Super help", size: 7326, wordcount: 380, snippet: "(HTML), which includes HTML <span class=\"searchmat…earchmatch\">help</span> is also provided via live"},
{ns: 0, title: "Help desk", size: 9491, wordcount: 1296, snippet: "A <span class=\"searchmatch\">help</span> desk is a …ated to a company's or institution's products and"}
]
}
};
function drawTableHor(data) {
    var table1 = document.getElementById("resultTable1");
    for (var i = 0; i < data.query.search.length; i++) {
      var row = table1.insertRow();
      for(var prop in data.query.search[i]) {
        if(prop !== 'title') continue;
          var cell = row.insertCell();
          cell.innerHTML = data.query.search[i][prop];
      }
    }
}
// alternative
function drawTableVert(data) {
    var table2 = document.getElementById("resultTable2");
    var rows = [], props = [];
    for(var prop in data.query.search[0]) {
        rows.push(table2.insertRow());
        props.push(prop);
    }
    rows.forEach(function(row, index) {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.query.search.length; i++) {
        if(props[index] !== 'title') continue;  
          var cell = row.insertCell();
          cell.innerHTML = data.query.search[i][props[index]];
      }
    });
}
// call each function passing your data
drawTableHor(data);
drawTableVert(data);
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0.5em;
}
td, th {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
<h1>Data is inserted "horizontally"</h1>
<table id="resultTable1"></table>
<br>
<h1>Data is inserted "vertically"</h1>
<table id="resultTable2"></table>
</div>
```

Hope it helps :)

**UPDATE**

```js
   
function build_wiki_search_url(pattern) {
var base_url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php";
var request_url = "?action=query&format=json&prop=info&inprop=url&list=search&srsearch=";
var url = base_url + request_url + pattern;
return url;
}
function drawTableHor(data) {
var table1 = document.getElementById("resultTable1");
for (var i = 0; i < data.query.search.length; i++) {
  var row = table1.insertRow();
  for(var prop in data.query.search[i]) {
    if(prop !== 'title') continue;
      var cell = row.insertCell();
      cell.innerHTML = data.query.search[i][prop];
  }
}
}
// UNCOMMENT everything commented out here to follow your original setup.
$(document).ready(function() {
/*$("#gosearch").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();*/
    var pattern = 'iteration'; //$("#search").val();
    var url = build_wiki_search_url(pattern);
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data) { 
            drawTableHor(data);
            }
   });
 //});
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0.5em;
}
td, th {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<h1>Data is inserted "horizontally"</h1>
<table id="resultTable1"></table>
</div>
```

I am looking there for 'iteration' word just for example. In your case you should uncomment a couple of things under my notice in the code. I mean click function on #search element.

Comment: First of all thanks, I can finally see any type of table in my html. However I am walled by two things: 
1. Same results are repeated 10 times so instead of 5 rows I have 50
2. I get the entire entry, how can I access to put in the table only a data I need (in my case only the title column). thanks

Comment: hi! 1) I don't see the whole code from which you took out this small part. But I can say that I used ES6 features like let/const, arrow function etc. Now I rewrote it all in plain ES5. Lets see if it helps. Also try to hide all the functionality in functions to avoid possible scope issues. 2) See updated code where I added a couple of checks (ifs) to output only `title`. Comment them out once you want to display all the data :)

Comment: I also added functions to deal with possible scope issues. Now it should be close :)

Comment: And check your JSON data just in case. There might be repeats too.

Comment: I get the edits to the code and they do work in extracting the title, however I still get repeated results. I can't really figure out why does that happen.

Comment: Btw I have updated my question to include the entire code so perhaps there is something fishy with the get request.

Comment: 1) why do you need `var format = "&format=json";` if you already have this part in `var request_url`?
2) `var request_url` should be without that space between `?` and `action...`
3) there is a total mess with brackets but I guess this is due to the copy/paste.
4) The most important thing - you have a cycle in your success function. Get rid of it because you repeat `drawTableHor` as many times as the number of entries the data has!
5) I updated the answer with your whole code.