# How to print this JSON in an html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json that I want to print in html an table. I just don't know how to print this JSON.

I tried this data['videos'] but nothing comes and this as well data.videos

```
{
  "videos": [
    {
      "title": "Martin Garrix feat. Bonn - No Sleep (Official Video)",
      "link": "/watch?v=JxzKNHfNRdI",
      "id": "JxzKNHfNRdI"
    },
    {
      "title": "Wiz Khalifa - No Sleep [Music Video]",
      "link": "/watch?v=KuVAeTHqijk",
      "id": "KuVAeTHqijk"
    },
    {
      "title": "Martin Garrix - No Sleep ft. Bonn (Lyrics)",
      "link": "/watch?v=c3uxLHn3-JQ",
      "id": "c3uxLHn3-JQ"
    },
    {
      "title": "Wiz Khalifa - No Sleep (D33pSoul Remix)",
      "link": "/watch?v=g5Yv00RsCe8",
      "id": "g5Yv00RsCe8"
    },
    {
      "title": "Wiz Khalifa - No Sleep [LYRICS ON SCREEN]",
      "link": "/watch?v=xkLzpRA5W_E",
      "id": "xkLzpRA5W_E"
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I print a table in HTML (using javascript). these details are in "data" variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create an HTML table rows in JS from iterated JSON array element objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45088360/create-an-html-table-rows-in-js-from-iterated-json-array-element-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need first to define a `table` in your html.

In javascript, you can retrieve this html element using [`querySelector('table')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

Then you can use [`insertRow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow) and [`insertCell`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/insertCell) to add the elements in the table.

```js
const data = {
  "videos": [
    { "title": "Martin Garrix feat. Bonn - No Sleep (Official Video)", "link": "/watch?v=JxzKNHfNRdI", "id": "JxzKNHfNRdI" },
    { "title": "Wiz Khalifa - No Sleep [Music Video]", "link": "/watch?v=KuVAeTHqijk", "id": "KuVAeTHqijk" },
    { "title": "Martin Garrix - No Sleep ft. Bonn (Lyrics)", "link": "/watch?v=c3uxLHn3-JQ", "id": "c3uxLHn3-JQ" },
    { "title": "Wiz Khalifa - No Sleep (D33pSoul Remix)", "link": "/watch?v=g5Yv00RsCe8", "id": "g5Yv00RsCe8" },
    { "title": "Wiz Khalifa - No Sleep [LYRICS ON SCREEN]", "link": "/watch?v=xkLzpRA5W_E", "id": "xkLzpRA5W_E" }
  ]
}

const table = document.querySelector('table')

for (const video of data.videos) {
  const row = table.insertRow()
  for (const value of Object.values(video)) {
    const cell = row.insertCell()
    cell.innerHTML = value
  }
}
```

```css
table tr td { padding: 5px; }
```

```html
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <th>title</th>
        <th>link</th>
        <th>id</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```